# Whats the cheapes price you can charge for a android app in google plays market

Tags: android, apk, google-play

Whats the cheapes price you can charge for a android app in the  google play market

Comment: Depends on the currency. And this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0.99 is the minimum for the master price. For non-US markets, probably per-country limits exist; I didn't test them all.

The price is a free entry field on Google Play, but there's a validator that won't let you specify less that 0.99.

Comment: haha I got dominated with the minus points